# Modprobe fails to load module wl on kernel 4.8

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I'm trying to get my wireless broadcom card to work on kernel 4.8. I used the bcmwl-kernel-source package to install the driver for it and it works just fine on kernel 4.4. The issue is that the wl module isn't getting loaded and is failing with the following error message

```
ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Looking at dmesg isn't particularly enlightening (to me)

```
[ 1484.224702] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_frame_data (err 0)
[ 1484.224744] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err 0)
[ 1484.224786] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err 0)
[ 1484.224805] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err 0)
[ 1484.224810] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_bss (err 0)
[ 1484.224825] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err 0)
[ 1484.224833] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err 0)
[ 1484.224838] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err 0)
[ 1484.224846] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_gtk_rekey_notify (err 0)
[ 1484.224869] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err 0)
[ 1484.224881] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err 0)
[ 1484.224895] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err 0)
[ 1484.224907] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err 0)
[ 1484.224919] wl: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err 0)
[ 1484.224945] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_frequency (err 0)
[ 1484.224955] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err 0)
[ 1484.224963] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_data (err 0)
[ 1484.224969] wl: Unknown symbol ieee80211_frequency_to_channel (err 0)
[ 1484.224980] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err 0)
```

I did see someone with a homemade patch that cold possibly fix this issue but I'm a little leery of trying it. If anyone has suggestions on how to fix this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because the `xenial` repos have the `wl` module compatible only with the `4.4` kernel.

You can install a patched version of `wl` from the `yakkety` repos this way:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
```

This version should work with the `4.8` kernel. Also make sure that Secure Boot is disabled if you are using UEFI.

If you have a 32-bit system, replace `amd64` with `i386` in the package name.

Comment: An high rep fellow you're probably familiar with says we should sign the modules instead of disabling secure boot, because secure boot is good ;-)

Comment: Secure Boot is no good.

Comment: I don't have secure boot enabled and I'm still getting the problem after downloading the package you recommended :/ .

Comment: That is weird. Try to boot with a previous 4.8 kernel.

Comment: I can ping mirrors.kernel.org, but I got a 404 on the wget step.